# ZF2 breadcrumbs are not working in child view

Tags: php, zend-framework2, breadcrumbs

I have a breadcrumb in a child view, but it is not showing any pages.
When I show it in the root view, everything is working correct

controller:

```
public function categoriesAction()
{
    $view = new ViewModel();

    $heading = new ViewModel(array(
        'headTitle' => 'Categorieën'
    ));

    $heading->setTemplate('templates/head');

    $view->addChild($heading, 'header')
         ->addChild($storecontent, 'content');
    return $view;
}
```

templates/head.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->navigation()->breadcrumbs()->setPartial('Application/partials/breadcrumbs'); ?>
```

When I place the above code in the root view, it is working. But I want it in the head so I can use it in more actions.

Comment: Setting a `template` to the `$view` should do. Eg: `$view->setTemplate('SOME_LAYOUT');`

Comment: unfortunately this is not working.  I've added `$view->setTemplate('catalog/categories');` before `$view->addChild($heading, 'header')`

Comment: I have tried it myself and it works with setting the template. Please check if your having `'templates/head'` and `Application/partials/breadcrumbs` path set in `template_map` correctly? Also check that you have `echo $this->header;` written in main layout .phtml file (`Eg: catalog/categories`).

Comment: Yes, I've set my template_map paths correctly otherwise i'm getting an error. In my breadcrumb partial I've added a static home link. This is showing in my header, but without the parent pages and the current page. Maybe it has to do with my routing?